# Can table columns be created by copying the datatype from another column ? (for ex like %type in Oracle)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For example, this is possible in Oracle. I wanted to know if snowflake has a similar concept.

```
CREATE TABLE Purchases
(
     purchase_date           calendar.date%type,
     customer_nr             customer.customer_nr%type,
     purchase_amount         numeric(10,2)
)
```

Comment: This concept is known as **"anchored data types"**

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's no way to do that right now. You can use system$typeof to check for a column type, but that can't be used in a create table statement.

Answer (score 0):

The referenceability that you have in your example is not available.  You can build a table by joining one or more tables and/or views together and build the column list with columns from any of the joins and any that you explicitly add to the list.  The key is to join on `1 = 2` or `FALSE`

#### Example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE TMP_X
AS
SELECT A."name" AS NAME  
    ,A."owner" AS OWNER
    ,B.STG_ARRAY 
    ,NULL::NUMERIC(10,2) AS PURCHASE_AMOUNT 
    ,NULL AS COMMENT 
FROM TABLE_A A
    JOIN TABLE_B B
        ON 1 = 2
;
```

- NAME - takes datatype from A."name" column
- OWNER - takes datatype from A."owner" column
- STG_ARRAY - takes datatype from B.STG_ARRAY column
- PURCHASE_AMOUNT - takes the datatype explicitly specified NUMERIC(10,2)
- COMMENT - no explicit datatype -- takes default datatype of VARCHAR(16777216)